# what is a good frequency for setting up snapshot replication in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2008-r2

My requirements:

1. I have a publisher database from which I intend to replicate to a subscriber.
2. Not all tables need to be replicated.
3. Amount of data could be ~20-30GB.

Given the above:

1. is snapshot replication a good choice?
2. if yes, what is the ideal frequency that can be setup? twice-a-day? thrice-a-day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshot Replication is a snapshot, moment-in-time, refresh of the published data.  It does not monitor or send updates between refreshes.

To answer your questions:

> is snapshot replication a good choice?

Snapshot Replication is best used when the data changes infrequently, such as a catalog update, or when the most up to date values are not required.  It depends on your application requirements.

> if yes, what is the ideal frequency that can be setup? twice-a-day?
>   thrice-a-day?

Again, it depends on your application requirements.  If your application requires constant refreshes then you should consider [Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx).  Otherwise, configure the frequency to meet your needs.

Comment: The application doesn't need realtime data, but the closer the better. A difference of 3 to 4 hours can be lived with.

Assuming that I will have around 30+ tables to be replicated and some of the tables running into a few million rows (some into a couple hundred million); will it be a issue in setting up a frequency of 4 hours?

During the time of frequent replication, will it lock the master database?

Answer (score 1):

1.1.is snapshot replication a good choice?

No,because you want to transfer data from some tabales and snapshot replication when applying snapshot to the subscriber the performance of the subscriber every time it generates new snapshot this is also resource consumption .Better use transactional replication it first generates snapshot and transfers transactions your database will be up to date.